# php71 conflict with php70 after disabling php71 repo

Tags: php, installation, conflict, yum

I am attempting to install php-zip (PHP 7.0) but am encountering:

```
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-7.0.23-1.el7.remi.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've...

- disabled all remi-php repos except for remi-php70.
- execute sudo `yum clean all`
- execute sudo `yum install php-zip`, `sudo yum install php70-zip` as well as `sudo yum install php70w-zip`.

All result in:

```
 Resolving Dependencies
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package php71w-common.x86_64 0:7.1.8-2.w7 will be installed
 --> Processing Conflict: php71w-common-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, webtatic was once in use and presented the conflict. I resolved my problem with:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable webtatic webtatic-archive webtatic-testing remi-php54  remi-php71
sudo yum clean all
```